# Почему нормальный терминал заменился на bash в Kali?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, terminal, sh

Только поставив Linux Kali под рутом открывался нормальный терминал - цветной и с показыванием текущей директории. Но как только я зашёл под нормальным юзером вместо терминала стал из той же кнопки открываться простейший bash, а именно только знак доллора в начале строки и без цветов. Как это исправить?

Comment: Это всё тот же bash, не пугайтесь. *Приглашение командной строки* (то, которое сейчас доллар) задаётся в `~/.bash_profile` через переменную окружения `PS1` (подробнее о том, что туда можно писать: http://www.calculate-linux.org/blogs/ru/193/show). Насчёт *раскраски прочего*, думаю, подойдёт https://habrahabr.ru/post/119436/

Comment: А как мне просто скопировать эти настройки с рута на основного юзера?

Comment: На примитивном не работает даже tab.

Comment: Скопируйте соответствующие части из `/root/.bash_profile`. Если этот файл отсутствует - посмотрите, не переопределяет ли `~/.bash_profile` настройки `PS1` и раскраски из `/etc/profile`.

Comment: Выложите, пожалуйста, в вопросе содержимое `~/.bash_profile` и `/root/.bash_profile`. Без них можно делать исключительно предположения.

Comment: Ни там, ни там `.bash_profile` нет (так говорит `ls -a` в обеих дир-ях).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49155/discussion-between-constantor-and-arhad).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

скорее всего, для этих пользователей указано использование разных оболочек.

узнать, какая оболочка указана, можно, например, командой:

```
$ getent passwd пользователь
```

в выводе последнее поле — это путь к оболочке:

```
пользователь:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/пользователь:/bin/bash
```

---

изменить оболочку можно, например, с помощью программы `chsh`:

```
$ sudo chsh -s /bin/sh пользователь
```